# Trying to use .reduce on an object

Tags: javascript

So I have an object that I need to sum a nested value for all the objects. My object looks like

```
const json = [
{
    "other_sum": "1",
    "summary": {
        "calculations": {
            "time": 10,
            "unit": 25
        },
        "updated": "2020-06-05"
    }
},
{
    "other_sum": "1",
    "summary": {
        "calculations": {
            "time": 20,
            "unit": 5
        },
        "updated": "2020-06-05"
    }
},
{
    "other_sum": "1",
    "summary": {
        "calculations": {
            "time": 5,
            "unit": 15
        },
        "updated": "2020-06-05"
    }
},
];
```

I need to sum all the "unit" values

I've been trying to use .reduce for this but it only works when I have 2 items in my object, onces I get a 3rd I get an error.

The rest of my code is the following:

```
const r = json.reduce((a, b) => a.summary.calculations.unit + b.summary.calculations.unit);
console.log(r);
```

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong atm.

Comment: You're missing the initial accumulator value. And you're accessing properties on your accumulator, but returning a number as the next accumulator value.

Comment: I bet this is just because you're not providing a starting value for the `reduce` (it's the second argument when calling it, and should be zero here).

Comment: Also `a` doesn't need the `summary.calc.unit` stuff, it's just a number. `json.reduce((a, e) => a + e.summary.calculations.unit, 0)`. Welcome to SO!

Comment: That's an array, not an object.

Comment: @Barmar `typeof ArrayInstance === 'object'`, but  `ArrayInstance instanceof Array`. I know you know that, but OP might not. Just a comment to correct you saying it's not an Object, when an Array is an Object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because thats not the way `reduce` works. Taken from [this article](https://codeburst.io/javascript-arrays-finding-the-minimum-maximum-sum-average-values-f02f1b0ce332) it works like this:

> Given
>
> ```
> arrSum = function(arr){
>   return arr.reduce(function(a,b){
>     return a + b
>   }, 0);
> }
> ```
>
> The function that we pass as the first parameter of the reduce method
> receives two parameters, `a` and `b`. In this code, `a` is our accumulator.
> It will accumulate our sum as our function works. `b` is the current
> value being processed.

So basically you are trying to access "summary" in the accumulator which is only a number. Here is the working snippet:

```js
json = [
{
    "other_sum": "1",
    "summary": {
        "calculations": {
            "time": 10,
            "unit": 25
        },
        "updated": "2020-06-05"
    }
},
{
    "other_sum": "1",
    "summary": {
        "calculations": {
            "time": 20,
            "unit": 5
        },
        "updated": "2020-06-05"
    }
},
{
    "other_sum": "1",
    "summary": {
        "calculations": {
            "time": 5,
            "unit": 15
        },
        "updated": "2020-06-05"
    }
},
];

const r = json.reduce((a, b) => a + b.summary.calculations.unit, 0);
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 4):

The first argument to the callback passed to .reduce is the accumulator, and the value returned from each iteration becomes the accumulator for the next iteration.

Therefore, the value called on the next item is going to be `a.summary.calculations.unit + b.summary.calculations.unit`, and the next time around, your callback will look for the nested property `a.summary.calculations.unit` on that returned value, which presumably does not exist.

You may want to change it to something along the lines of:

```
const r = json.reduce((a, b) => a + b.summary.calculations.unit, 0);
```

where 0 is the initial value for your accumulator.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), as always, is a good reference.

Comment: Nitpick: I recommend not using `b` here--what's `b`? It makes sense for `sort`'s callback because you're comparing a pair of numbers that have an even relationship. I recommend `e` for element here.

Answer (score 2):

The first value of the reduce function is not an object but the previous value that you are returned. You can change your code to this.

```
 json.reduce((total, b) => total+ b.summary.calculations.unit, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use my `dig` function:

```js
function dig(obj, func){
  let v;
  if(obj instanceof Array){
    for(let i=0,l=obj.length; i<l; i++){
      v = obj[i]; func(v, i, obj);
      if(typeof v === 'object')dig(v, func);
    }
  }
  else{
    for(let i in obj){
      v = obj[i]; func(v, i, obj);
      if(typeof v === 'object')dig(v, func);
    }
  }
}
const json = [
  {
    "other_sum": "1",
    "summary": {
      "calculations": {
          "time": 10,
          "unit": 25
      },
      "updated": "2020-06-05"
    }
  },
  {
    "other_sum": "1",
    "summary": {
      "calculations": {
        "time": 20,
         "unit": 5
      },
      "updated": "2020-06-05"
    }
  },
  {
    "other_sum": "1",
    "summary": {
      "calculations": {
        "time": 5,
        "unit": 15
      },
      "updated": "2020-06-05"
    }
  }
];
let unitTotal = 0, timeTotal = 0;
dig(json, (v, k)=>{
  if(k === 'unit'){
    unitTotal += v;
  }
  else if(k === 'time'){
    timeTotal += v;
  }
});
console.log('unitTotal: '+unitTotal);
console.log('timeTotal: '+timeTotal);
```